# How can I detect touch events on a UIImageView inside a deep hierarchy of UIViews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, touch

I am developing a simple game on iPhone and I started with a View based application, and through the `UIViewController` I am loading a custom `UIView` that contains some more `UIView`s and some `UIImageView`s. I want to detect touch events on some of the `UIImageView`s, but I wasn't able so far.

I've created a second project for testing purposes and figured that `UIImageView`s handle touch events when the hierarchy is like :

> `UIViewController` -> `UIView` -> `UIImageView`,

but when it's like :

> `UIViewController` -> `UIView` -> `UIView` -> `UIImageView`

they are not detected.

Notes:
 - `userInteractionEnabled` is `YES` in all cases
 - all `UIViews` and `UIImageViews` I mention above are custom subclasses.

Can you think of any reason why, when a custom `UIImageView` gets deeper in the view hierarchy can't receive touch events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Touches take a long and circuitous route to their destination.  Officially, they go up the responder chain, which starts at the first responder, and then goes from the deepest-touch-including view to its view controller, to the next-up touch-including view, etc.

But the real picture is even more complicated, since, in finding the deepest-touch-including view to go to, the touch essentially "asks" the highest-level view for that info by calling the `hitTest:withEvent:` method.  This allows some superviews to hijack touches, which can be very useful, as in `UIScrollView`, which sometimes does things (scrolls/zooms) before its subviews know what's going on.

Here are a few tips to help determine why a view might not be responding to touches:

- Override `[hitTest:withEvent:`][1](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:) on each of your views and `NSLog` when they get hit to see who is being considered for the responder chain.
- Use the undocumented (and-therefore-take-it-out-before-you-submit) `UIView` method [`recursiveDescription`](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIView#-recursiveDescription) to check the frames of all your views at runtime.  Views display beyond their frame sizes by default, so they may appear ok, but have smaller sizes logically than visually -- and the touches respond based on the logical (not visual) sizes.
- This may sound dumb, but double-check that your methods are correctly connected to the output you're looking for.  For example, if you're expecting your - [MyClass buttonPressed] method to get called when a `UIButton` is touched, double-check that you've added your `MyClass` instance and `@selector(buttonPressed)` as a target/action pair for that button.
- If none of those work, override `touchesBegan:withEvent:` with `NSLog` messages to see where the touches are going up the responder chain.

And, you already know this, but watch out for the `userInteractionEnabled` flag!

Hopefully that's enough to isolate the problem.

Comment: First of all thank you for the quick response!  
I just had the time to examine your tips. The problem was that I didn't initialize the UIImageView with `initWithFrame`. It was your second tip that made me suspect that this was the problem : "Views display beyond their frame sizes by default, so they may appear ok, but have smaller sizes logically than visually -- and the touches respond based on the logical (not visual) sizes."